# Odd overlay effect when trying to add portrait pictures to landscape pixelBuffer

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, core-image

I'm trying to create a video from an array of images that are stored on a disk. These images can be portrait or landscape. The code below is horrifically unoptimised and I am the furthest thing away from an AVFoundation guru, so I'm looking to a bit of help as to why this might not be working. I get the result in the image below - its almost like the image is being overlayed on a previous frame.

[image: Image being overlayed on a previous frame]

Here is the code used to generate the sample `CVBuffer` to add to the `pixelBufferAdaptor`:

```
class FrameCreator {

func create(from image: URL, pixelBufferPool: CVPixelBufferPool, size: CGSize) -> CVBuffer? {
    let context = CIContext(mtlDevice: MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()!)
    context.clearCaches()
    var pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer?
    
    // can be removed
    precondition(CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer(nil, pixelBufferPool, &pixelBuffer) == kCVReturnSuccess)
    
    
    let ciImage = CIImage(contentsOf: image, options: [CIImageOption.applyOrientationProperty: true])!
    let imageSize = ciImage.extent.size
    if imageSize.height < imageSize.width {
        let horizontalRatio = size.width / imageSize.width
        let verticalRatio = size.height / imageSize.height

        let aspectRatio = max(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio)
        
        let newSize = CGSize(width: imageSize.width * aspectRatio, height: imageSize.height * aspectRatio)
        
        let x = newSize.width < size.width ? (size.width - newSize.width) / 2 : 0
        let y = newSize.height < size.height ? (size.height - newSize.height) / 2 : 0
        
        context.render(ciImage, to: pixelBuffer!, bounds: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height), colorSpace: ciImage.colorSpace)
    } else {
        let targetSize = size
        let imageSize = ciImage.extent.size

        let widthFactor = targetSize.width / imageSize.width
        let heightFactor = targetSize.height / imageSize.height
        let scaleFactor = min(widthFactor, heightFactor)

        let scaledImage = ciImage.transformed(by: CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleFactor, y: scaleFactor))
        
        let movedImage = scaledImage.transformed(by: CGAffineTransform(translationX: (size.width / 2) - (scaledImage.extent.size.width / 2), y: 0))

        context.render(movedImage, to: pixelBuffer!)
    }
    
    precondition(CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!, []) == kCVReturnSuccess)
    defer { precondition(CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!, []) == kCVReturnSuccess) }
    
    let bytes = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!)!.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self), count: CVPixelBufferGetDataSize(pixelBuffer!))
    precondition(bytes.contains(where: { $0 != 0 }))
    
    return pixelBuffer
}
}
```

And here is where its called:

```
func addFrame(frameNumber: Int, image: URL) {
    let frameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: Int64(renderSettings.timescale / renderSettings.fps),
                                   timescale: renderSettings.timescale)
    let presentationTime = CMTimeMultiply(frameDuration, multiplier: Int32(frameNumber))
    
    print("Frame to be added at: \(presentationTime)")
    
    if let frame = frameCreator.create(from: image, 
                                         pixelBufferPool: pixelBufferAdaptor.pixelBufferPool!,
                                         size: renderSettings.size) {
        pixelBufferAdaptor.append(frame, withPresentationTime: presentationTime)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.delegate?.didAddFrame(frameNumber, totalFrames: self.images.count)
        }
    } else {
        // handle error
    }
}
```